# Swift: UIControl in TableViewController found nil when called by ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, controller, null

I have two `viewControllers` in the storyboard, a `ViewController` (root) and a `TableViewController`, that are linked by a push segue.

The `TableViewController` acts as a setting page of the app and multiple `UIControls` such as `UISegmentedControl` and `UISwitch` are put in it. These `UIControls` are linked to the `TableViewController` via `IBOutlets`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
```

However, when I call these `UIControls` in the `ViewController` by:

```
let tableView: TableViewController = TableViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

if tableView.mySwitch.isOn {
//perform actions
}
```

Error pops up at the if-statment:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I thought it was because the `TableViewController` has not been loaded when the `UIControls` are being called, thus I have tried calling the `viewDidLoad()` of tableView first, but the error still remains.

What should I do? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you instantiating your viewController via `TableViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` if you have defined it in storyboard?
For storyboard defined VC you have to use:- 
`var storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var someViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeViewController") as! SomeViewController`

Comment: @Aks Thank you very much. I didn't know I could instantiate it in this way. Your solution worked with the suggestion from Andreas Oetjen. However, the UIControl variables called by the ViewController do not change their value neither after pressing the UISwitch nor UISegmentedControl in the ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not directly call `viewDidLoad`, this is done by UIKit after the view is being loaded. And the view is loaded when the view needs to be displayed.

If you need to access the outlets before, you can force loading by

```
tableView.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

But remember:

- Maybe it's better to do the outlet stuff *inside* `viewDidLoad` of the involved controller, and not from outside.
- You should not name the controller variable `tableView`. That name suggest to be a *view* and not a controller. Better name it `tableViewCtrl` or so.